# CentOS 7 Install Error: Call to StartServiceByName Timeout

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, installation, centos7

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 on my HP Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2 server. I'm attempting this through the iLO4 IRC and virtual media. I'm booting 'CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-Minimal'. I get to the first install menu (i.e., install, check media and install, troubleshoot, ...) and press install, then it appears a sequence of tests begin (green 'OK's) - these tests take a lot longer than they did when I did a 'local install' on a home computer. At the end of the tests, i.e., before I get to the main GUI install screen (where you setup network, timezone, disk partitions, etc) I get this error:

[image]

I tried with the minimal image ~3 times - same outcome each time. I then tried the DVD install image - same problem.

Note that is appears I'm uploading the virtual media at ~60kB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

Note: Before I did this I 'ran' the Sept 2014 SPP - appeared to complete error free.

Went through it again, here are the only errors / warnings that I came across:

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT EDIT:

Remove 'quite' from install command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda asks DBus to check with NetworkManager if it's not connecting or if it's not connected already, thus, if there is network connectivity (so it won't ask about VNC). DBus will talk to NM but it seems that the call to _get_proxy (which creates a proxy object to talk to DBus) failed.

So it seems there is a problem with DBus, but it's not clear just from this stack trace.

While the "OK" prompts are showing, press ESC so it shows all the messages. Pay attention to them and see if you can find some other error related to DBus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply gtirloni. Unfortunately during my re-attempt the iLO appeared to die - I think it might just be hung, but won't know more until Monday. Until then, do you think you could hypothesize some potential causes? For example, am I going to be looking at hardware incompatibility? Could the B120i storage controller be causing problems? What else could it be? The server has 4 Ethernet ports (3 in use), but no connection to the internet. I guess I'm just wondering if it could be a simple fix - for some reason I believe that will be unlikely.